# Best way to read, process and write multiple text files (upwards of 100k) each sized up to 900mb and write them to different location

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently tying to read multiple (100k) huge text file each sized more than 900mb (where the information is present orderly line by line, what is the best way to read, do some processing (filter based on some specific information in the text present in each line) and lastly grouping those lines with the same condition together based on my filtering condition and write them to different file with different names based on the filtering process.

Note that each line of text from every file I read might end up in different file

Currently I am reading them line by line, processing them line by line and writing them line by line to new a file with a new name/appending them line by line to the file if the specific filename has been created.

Is there any more efficient way to do it, will it be faster if I load specific number of lines into memory and do the processing later on ?

Thank You.

Improve the performance as I know that IO operation in .net is quite slow.

Comment: Just a proposal but maybe you can load the datasets into a database, do the calculation and export the data back to a csv or whatever you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any more efficient way to do it, will it be faster if I load specific number of lines into memory and do the processing later on ?

According to your description you are only processing each line one time.So your algorithm is should be optimal, and that is a good start.

That does not necessarily mean you cannot improve performance. I would recommend starting by doing some profiling so you have some idea what step takes time. If it is the filtering improving the reading/writing will not help. Some ideas for things you could try:

- If you are closing the file for each line you write, consider keeping the files open until the end of the program. That should allow the OS to buffer writes better.
- Buy a faster harddrive, or split the reading and writing to multiple drives.

It *might* also be possible to parallelize some work, or use async/await, but multi threaded development is difficult and IO typically does not parallelize well. So I would only consider this if you are comfortable with thread safety and multi threaded design, and confident that it will actually help performance.

You could perhaps also consider using some compression for your files, files like log files often compress very well, and that might save enough IO to be worth the CPU-hit. But this will likely only be a benefit if whatever is creating the files can compress them at the same time.

But again, start by doing some profiling. I can only make guesses about what takes most time in your code, and even experienced programmers often guess incorrectly.